# Why Does index.php reappear in url even after removing it via htaccess

Tags: codeigniter

My question is that, I have removed `index.php` in `codeignitor 3` via following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

but when i redirect from one controller to another `index.php` reappear in the URL, As far as i am working within same controller it remains hidden.

Comment: Did you remove it from `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` in `/applications/config.php` (line 38)?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: @ourmandave ..... thanks that worked. I had not removed that from config page.